# NullPointerException при подключению к бд Oracle

Tags: oracle, jdbc, java

Я пишу метод для обновления пароля при возникновении ошибки ORA-28001: the password has expired. При подключении к бд выдается NullPointerException:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at PasswordExpiredExeption.ResetPassword(PasswordExpiredExeption.java:46)
>     at PasswordExpiredExeption.<init>(PasswordExpiredExeption.java:17)
>     at CRUD.listCompany(CRUD.java:47)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:14)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>     at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

```
public class PasswordExpiredExeption extends SQLException {

public PasswordExpiredExeption() {
    System.out.println("Password Expired");
    System.out.println("Update Password");
    ResetPassword();
}

public void ResetPassword(){
    String user = "user";
    String password = "qwerty";
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@";
    Properties props = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    props = new Properties();

    props.put("user", user);
    props.put("password", password);
    props.put("OCINewPassword", password);
    try {
        System.out.println(
                props.getProperty("user") + "   " +
                        props.getProperty("password") + "   " +
                        props.getProperty("OCINewPassword")
        );
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
        connection.close();
    }catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println(connection.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Password is update");
}
}
```

**Обновление**

На 46 строчке находится `System.out.println(connection.toString());`,
то есть сам connection равен null.

`e.printStackTrace()` выдает `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28001: the password has expired`

Answer (score 1):

я, конечно, мимо проходил, но вы делаете две ужасные вещи:

1. Суете некоторую логику, да еще и работающую с БД, (сброс пароля) в исключение.
2. Вызываете эту логику из конструктрора.

Не надо так.

Теперь к вопросу: какое конкретно выражение находится на `46` строке в файле `PasswordExpiredExeption.java`?

Answer (score 1):

[[@GRamis](/users/31254/gramis)](/users/31254/gramis) так у вас наверняка происходит ошибка при открытии соединения. Поместите строку e.printStackTrace(); первой и посмотрите, какое исключение на самом деле вываливается.

Ну и присоединюсь к [[@Nofate](/users/1984/nofate)](/users/1984/nofate): дизайн ужасный. Исключения -- это пустышки, которые не должны нести ничего, кроме информации об ошибке.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, через jdbc пароль нельзя поменять.
Только через OCI.